# How to throw jsp variable into reactjs file?

Tags: spring, jsp, reactjs

I am developing an application using spring framework and react js. In my jsp file I have ${variable} that has been injected. How could I pass this variable to my reactjs file ? I tried to write ${variable} in my js file but it wont replace with the value when the js file has been rendered.

Comment: that's because your javascript has nothing to do with JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an ajax call to the server and then process the result in javascript

componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get(url, function(result) {
     //do something
    }.bind(this));
  },

You can read the reactjs tutorial

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html